# scrapy install on debian

Tags: python, linux, debian, scrapy

I got an issue, scrapy was working fine until I uninstalled it and reinstalled.
Since 0.24 wasn't available at the time on debian I added the ubuntu repo to my /etc/pat/sources.list.d and installed it with apt-get as described here : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/ubuntu.html

today when seeing that it was available on debian I apt-get remove scrapy-0.24 (the one installed from ubuntu repo) and did apt-get install python-scrapy

now when I do a `scrapy shell www.google.fr` here's the output :

```
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [default] DEBUG: Retrying <GET file:///home/lotso/www.google.fr> (failed 1 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/lotso/www.google.fr'
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [default] DEBUG: Retrying <GET file:///home/lotso/www.google.fr> (failed 2 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/lotso/www.google.fr'
2014-12-07 22:08:26+0100 [default] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET file:///home/lotso/www.google.fr> (failed 3 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/lotso/www.google.fr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 50, in run
shell.start(url=url, spider=spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 45, in start
self.fetch(url, spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 90, in fetch
reactor, self._schedule, request, spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
result.raiseException()
  File "<string>", line 2, in raiseException
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/lotso/www.google.fr'
```

as you can imagine `➜  ~  pwd
/home/lotso`

If I change directory it appends the directory where I am
I tried uninstalling python-scrapy with purge then install it through pip and I got the same issue

I'm at a loss now, I suspect an environment variable somewhere but failed to solve it myself...

Comment: You aren't passing a fully qualified URL to your script.

Comment: omg....can I take my question back ? thanks for opening my eyes :)

Comment: Got an example here: `scrapy shell 'http://scrapy.org'` ->http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#example-of-shell-session

Answer (score 3):

this method works with scrapy 1.0.3 and debian 8.2

1. install the dependencies to setup
   `sudo apt-get install python-twisted python-libxml2 python- libxml2-dbg python-openssl python-simplejson`
2. download scrapy from this site: http://scrapy.org/ (for example: choose tarball)
3. decompress and setup
   `tar zxf Scrapy-X.X.X.tar.gz;
   cd Scrapy-X.X.X;
   sudo python setup.py install`

Answer (score 2):

## HOW to install Scrapy 1.3 with Python 2.7 on Debian 8 (x86)

Restart your machine, run from root (or use sudo).

```
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install virtualenv
```

Basic info about virtual environment: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

```
virtual ENV
cd ENV
source bin/activate
```

Virtual env is activated,... (command "deactivate" simply deactivate it)

```
apt-get install gcc
apt-get install python-pip
apt-get install cython
apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install scrapy
pip install scrapy --upgrade
```

This worked for me, I applied it on empty installation.

Comment: Tested on x64 Debian 8, Pyton 3.4
Just installed Scrapy 1.4.0